# Elasticsearch-JDBC - Initial Setup - ClassNotFoundException - JDBCFeeder

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I am getting the below exception after downloading elasticsearch-jdbc and running a simple script for the first time.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.xbib.tools.JDBCFeeder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.xbib.tools.Runner.main(Runner.java:25)
```

Comment: What script did you run?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the class was renamed to `JDBCImporter` at some point, but the included sample-scripts were not updated.

The samples start to work for me when I change them to `JDBCImporter`.

See e.g. the [samples on the main page](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc), which use JDBCImporter.

I have also reported [Issue 633](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc/issues/633) to get this fixed in the project itself.